# Interval on a number line

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I would like to make an interval on a number line that looks like these.
[image: interval on a number line]

This is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings,decorations.text,arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
    markings,% switch on markings
    mark=% actually add a mark
      between positions 0 and 1 step 1mm
      with
      {
        \draw[black!50] (-2pt,-3pt) -- (2pt,3pt);
      }
    }]
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw[-{Stealth[scale=1]}] (-.5,0) -- (9.5,0) ;
    \foreach \x in  {0,1,...,9}
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};
    \draw[{Straight Barb[scale=2]}-{Bracket[scale=2]}] (2,0)--(7,0);
    \end{scope}
    \draw [postaction={decorate}] (2,0)--(7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the slashes to go all the way to the interval boundaries but not over?

Answer (score 1):

You could draw the arrow tips manually and include them as part of the area that is to be filled with the lines which are implemented here via a pattern.

It looks very messy – and it is – but the main interface are the keys *without* `@` that are a combination of a left delimiter and a right delimiter and have the same syntax as arrow tips.

They each take one argument: the angle of the lines (i.e. the pattern angle). The delimiters are `angle`, `bracket` and none.

The styles `numline area` and `numline delimiters` can be adjusted to change the appearence.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns.meta}
\tikzset{
  @numline/@l/.style 2 args   ={insert path={  ([shift={(#1)}]  up:4pt)    coordinate (area_start) #2 ++(down:8pt)}},
  @numline/@r/.style 2 args   ={insert path={#2([shift={(#1)}]down:4pt)                            #2 ++(up:8pt)}},
  @numline/@langle/.style 2 args  ={insert path={  ([shift={(#1)}]  3pt,  4pt) coordinate (area_start) -- (#1) -- +( 3pt, -4pt)}},
  @numline/@rangle/.style 2 args  ={insert path={#2([shift={(#1)}] -3pt, -4pt)                         -- (#1) -- +(-3pt,  4pt)}},
  @numline/@lbracket/.style 2 args={insert path={  ([shift={(#1)}]  2pt,  4pt) coordinate (area_start) -| (#1) |- +( 2pt, -4pt)}},
  @numline/@rbracket/.style 2 args={insert path={#2([shift={(#1)}] -2pt, -4pt)                         -| (#1) |- +(-2pt,  4pt)}},
  /utils/create to paths for combo/.style args={#1_#2}{
    #1-#2/.style={to path={[insert path/.expanded={
      edge[path only, numline area={##1}, @numline/@#1_#2=--](\tikztotarget)
      edge[path only, numline delimiters, @numline/@#1_#2=]  (\tikztotarget)}]}},
    @numline/@#1_#2/.style={to path={[@numline/@l#1={\tikztostart}{},
                                      @numline/@r#2={\tikztotarget}{##1}] ##1 (area_start)}}},
  /utils/create to paths for combo/.list={
    angle_bracket, angle_angle,  bracket_angle, bracket_bracket,
         _bracket, angle_,              _angle, bracket_}}
\tikzset{
  numline delimiters/.style={thick, draw},
  numline area/.style={pattern color=gray, thin, pattern={Lines[angle=#1]}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-Stealth] (-.5,0) -- (9.5,0) ;
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
  \draw[shift=(right:\x)] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};

\path (2,0) to[angle-bracket=80] (7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-Stealth] (-.5,0) -- (9.5,0) ;
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
  \draw[shift=(right:\x)] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};

\path (2,0) to[bracket-angle=-80] (7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-Stealth] (-.5,0) coordinate (start) -- (9.5,0) coordinate (end);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
  \draw[shift=(right:\x)] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};

\path (start) to[-angle  =-80] (2,0);
\path (7,0)   to[bracket-=-80] (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-Stealth] (-.5,0) coordinate (start) -- (9.5,0) coordinate (end);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
  \draw[shift=(right:\x)] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\x$};

\path (start) to[-bracket=80] (2,0);
\path (7,0)   to[angle-  =80] (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I increased the size of the delimiters and pattern so it has better readability in print.